# Why do the authors subtract the median in this measure for adjusted average app rating?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm just reading the paper "Is this App Safe? A Large Scale Study on Application
Permissions and Risk Signals" by Chia et al. (available [here from ntnu.no](http://q2s.ntnu.no/~chia/paper/app-www.pdf)). On page 3, they calculate an interesting measure, the adjusted average rating:

```
avgra = (avgr − 3) ∗ log(#rating)
```

`avgr` is the average rating of an app, and `#rating` is the total number of ratings for this app.

I do understand that they log transform the number of ratings to get rid of the skewness in the data. What I do not understand is why are they subtracting 3 (the median if I interpret their explanation correctly) from the rating? Is it to factor in extreme values with a higher loading?

Additionally, a reference I could cite regarding the explanation would of course be even better :)

Comment: Why not ask the authors of the paper?

Comment: I guess the point is that (average-median) is zero (or close to zero) if there is no skewness in data. then they adjust the log transformation by this av-median term that looks interesting and useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is just to get a metric centered around 0, where negative values represent the confidence that an app is "bad" (or unsafe) and positive values the confidence that is "good" (safe).